# crosstool-ng build fail

Tags: gcc, cross-platform, beagleboard

I am using a guide from [Free-Electrons.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20121101075104/http://free-electrons.com/doc/training/embedded-linux/labs.pdf)

I am trying to install the crosstool-ng compiler and have go to the point where you run the following command under the title **Produce The Toolchain** on page 6.

```
./ct-ng build
```

It should be noted that the article says to use **Release 1.4.2 of Crosstool-ng** which I have done.

During the build it will fail saying that it can not download **sstrip**  which appears to be documented **[here](http://old.nabble.com/Crosstool-NG:-error-retrieving-sstrip.c-td21789614.html)**

**Example of Fail:**

```
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'sstrip'
[ERROR]    Could not retrieve 'sstrip'.
[00:10] / make: *** [build] Error 1
```

In short the reason is that the repository has move and the posted solution is:

```
Yes, the buildroot repository has migrated to git from svn after the 1.4.0
release was out, so 1.4.0 still uses the old URL.

Please try:
http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/download/crosstool-ng/01-fixes/1.4.0/002-sstrip-URL.patch
And while you're at it, you should also apply both of:
http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/download/crosstool-ng/01-fixes/1.4.0/000-glibc-2.8+_from_cvs_if_addon.patch
http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/download/crosstool-ng/01-fixes/1.4.0/001-glibc_force_ports_ARM_MIPS.patch
```

OK so installing the patch was a little weird but based on the [README](https://web.archive.org/web/20100707133950/http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/download/crosstool-ng/01-fixes/00-README)

> The patches should be applied directly at the top-level of the
> crosstool-NG directory with a command like:
>
> ```
> patch -p1 < ..../xxx-blabla.patch
> ```
>
> (replace ..../xxx-blabla.patch with an actual patch name)

So what I did was:

```
%> patch -p1 /felabs/sysdev/toolchain/crosstool-ng-1.4.2/scripts/build/tools/200-sstrip.sh<002-sstrip-URL.patch
```

I am not sure if the above command was correct but upon running the **./ct-ng build** it now downloads the sscript so I guess it's Ok.

I should have applied the other two patches but was not sure of the source file, anyway the new build continued to this point:

```
[INFO ]  Build started 20110629.182838
[INFO ]  Checking environment sanity
[INFO ]  Building environment variables
[EXTRA]  Preparing working directories
[WARN ]  You did not specify the build system. That's OK, I can guess...
[EXTRA]  Installing user-supplied crosstool-NG configuration
[EXTRA]  =================================================================
[EXTRA]  Dumping internal crosstool-NG configuration
[EXTRA]    Building a toolchain for:
[EXTRA]      build  = i686-linux-gnu
[EXTRA]      host   = i686-linux-gnu
[EXTRA]      target = arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi
[EXTRA]  Dumping internal crosstool-NG configuration: done in 0.05s (at 00:01)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'ltrace_0.5.orig'
[EXTRA]    Saving 'ltrace_0.5.orig.tar.gz' to local storage
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'strace-4.5.17'
[EXTRA]    Saving 'strace-4.5.17.tar.bz2' to local storage
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs: done in 8.54s (at 00:09)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Extracting and patching toolchain components
[INFO ]  Extracting and patching toolchain components
[EXTRA]    Extracting 'linux-2.6.29'
[EXTRA]    Patching 'linux-2.6.29'
[EXTRA]    Extracting 'gmp-4.2.4'
[EXTRA]    Patching 'gmp-4.2.4'
[EXTRA]    Extracting 'mpfr-2.4.1'
[EXTRA]    Patching 'mpfr-2.4.1'
[EXTRA]    Extracting 'binutils-2.19.1'
[EXTRA]    Patching 'binutils-2.19.1'
[EXTRA]    Extracting 'gcc-4.3.2'
[EXTRA]    Patching 'gcc-4.3.2'
[EXTRA]    Extracting 'uClibc-0.9.30.1'
[EXTRA]    Patching 'uClibc-0.9.30.1'    
[EXTRA]    Extracting 'libelf-0.8.10'
[EXTRA]    Patching 'libelf-0.8.10'
[EXTRA]    Extracting 'sstrip'
[EXTRA]    Patching 'sstrip'
[EXTRA]    Extracting 'gdb-6.8'
[ERROR]    Build failed in step 'Extracting and patching toolchain components'
[ERROR]    Error happened in '/home/swamprat/felabs/sysdev/toolchain/crosstool-ng-1.4.2/scripts/functions' in function 'CT_DoExecLog' (line unknown, sorry)
[ERROR]          called from '/home/swamprat/felabs/sysdev/toolchain/crosstool-ng-1.4.2/scripts/functions' at line # 535 in function 'CT_Extract'
[ERROR]          called from '/home/swamprat/felabs/sysdev/toolchain/crosstool-ng-1.4.2/scripts/build/debug/300-gdb.sh' at line # 60 in function 'do_debug_gdb_extract'
[ERROR]          called from '/home/swamprat/felabs/sysdev/toolchain/crosstool-ng-1.4.2/scripts/build/debug.sh' at line # 28 in function 'do_debug_extract'
[ERROR]          called from '/home/swamprat/felabs/sysdev/toolchain/crosstool-ng-1.4.2/scripts/crosstool-NG.sh' at line # 470 in function 'main'
[ERROR]    Look at '/usr/local/xtools/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/build.log' for more info on this error.
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 1:53.45)
[01:53] / make: *** [build] Error 2
```

**This is where I'm stuck any ideas ?**

Comment: You forgot to mention the findings from the mentioned `build.log` file. The cause will be described a lot more verbose there than in the more succinct output you get when running `ct-ng build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the latest 1.11.x release of [Crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/)

Answer (score 1):

possibility and solution:

- **you use the xxx.tar.gz**

solution:

use `xxx.tar.bz2` instead of `xxx.tar.gz`

- **incomplete tar ball file**

no matter, you download the tar or use crosstool auto download for you, just:

solution:

makesure the tar file, such as xxx.tar.bz2 is `intact, not broken`

more details, please refer my post:
[crosstool build error：in function ‘CT_Extract’](http://www.crifan.com/crosstool_build_failed_in_step_extracting_and_patching_toolchain_components_in_function_ct_doexeclog_line_unknown_sorry/)